# how to get OMPL library loaded for default panda arm

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to get OMPL library loaded for default panda arm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348982/how-to-get-ompl-library-loaded-for-default-panda-arm/) by [AndreV84](https://answers.ros.org/users/53273/andrev84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-10**:
This seems like a cross-post of [ros-planning/moveit#2020](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2020). Please don't do that.

**Comment by [AndreV84](https://answers.ros.org/users/53273/andrev84/) on 2020-04-10**:
Hi gvdhoom,
Thank you for your valuable response.
I will adjust the topic, as there are several issues in various configurations that I experience when trying to set up basic environment.
Will that work for you ?
Regards,
Andrei

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-10**:
It's not really a valuable response at all. However, it is a necessary one, as cross-posting is counterproductive.

My suggestion would be to either close this post, or the one on the MoveIt issue tracker. If you have more information, expand the post you decide to keep.

**Comment by [AndreV84](https://answers.ros.org/users/53273/andrev84/) on 2020-04-10**:
@gvdhoom. The issue have been resolved. How do I close the current thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reinstalled OS: Bionic 18.04 armhf;

Following https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full ros-melodic-moveit ros-melodic-panda-moveit-config -y
echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo apt install python-rosdep python-rosinstall python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential
```

then I created a folder at `~` name_ws, copied github package to `src`, initiated `rosdep init` and `rosdep update`
somehow works;
resolved

---

Originally posted by [AndreV84](https://answers.ros.org/users/53273/andrev84/) with karma: 16 on 2020-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0